# dplyr summarise data.table: refer to columns that you just created

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

Referring to columns that were just created in dplyr works on tbl_dfs but not on data.tables. Is that expected? I do not see a note on this in the documentation.

Here is the reproducible example:

```
library("hflights")
library("plyr")
library("dplyr")
library("data.table")

hflights_df <- tbl_df(hflights)

summarise(hflights_df,
      delay = mean(DepDelay, na.rm = TRUE),
      delay2 = 2*delay)
## Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
## 
##      delay  delay2
## 1 9.444951 18.8899

hflights_dt <- data.table(hflights_df)

summarise(hflights_dt,
      delay = mean(DepDelay, na.rm = TRUE),
      delay2 = 2*delay)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'delay' not found
```

And here is my sessionInfo:

```
sessionInfo()
## R version 3.0.2 (2013-09-25)
## Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0 (64-bit)
## 
## locale:
## [1] en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/en_GB.UTF-8/C/en_GB.UTF-8/C
## 
## attached base packages:
## [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
## 
## other attached packages:
## [1] data.table_1.9.2  dplyr_0.2         plyr_1.8.1        hflights_0.1     
## [5] andRstuff_1.0     devtools_1.5.0.99 tikzDevice_0.7.0  filehash_2.2-2   
## 
## loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
##  [1] assertthat_0.1 compiler_3.0.2 digest_0.6.4   evaluate_0.5.3 grid_3.0.2    
##  [6] httr_0.3       memoise_0.1    parallel_3.0.2 Rcpp_0.11.1    RCurl_1.95-4.1
## [11] reshape2_1.2.2 stringr_0.6.2  tools_3.0.2    whisker_0.3-2
```

Edit:
This works (similar to the suggestions by jazzurro and KFB):

```
summarise(tbl_df(hflights_dt),
      delay = mean(DepDelay, na.rm = TRUE),
      delay2 = 2*delay)
## Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
## 
##      delay  delay2
## 1 9.444951 18.8899
```

This does not work, though:

```
summarise(tbl_dt(hflights_dt),
      delay = mean(DepDelay, na.rm = TRUE),
      delay2 = 2*delay)
## Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'delay' not found
```

Comment: `hflights_dt <- as.data.table(hflights_df)` works for me instead of `data.table(hflights_df)`

Comment: @jazzurro thanks but see my comment to KFBs answer.  I only consider this a workaround.

Comment: Have a look at [this closed dplyr issue](https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/495).

Comment: @Arun Thanks.  That looks like being the issue here.  It is not obvious to me why it works in `mutate` and does not in `summarise` though.  And is it documented somewhere?

Comment: On documentation, you'll have to ask the dplyr developers. The reason it works with `mutate` is because they use a for-loop and assign by reference, 1 column at a time. Have a look at `dplyr:::mutate_.grouped_dt`.

Answer (score 0):

### use as.data.table instead:

```
> hflights_df <- tbl_df(hflights)
> hflights_dt <- as.data.table(hflights_df)
> summarise(hflights_dt,
+           delay = mean(DepDelay, na.rm = TRUE),
+           delay2 = 2*delay)
Source: local data frame [1 x 2]

     delay  delay2
1 9.444951 18.8899
```

Comment: that works but is a workaround only.  this is obviously a toy example.  my real usecase is the result of a call to `data.table::fread()`

Comment: Note that this works because `class(hflights_dt)` is then `"tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.table" "data.frame"`.  So the `tbl_df` method of `summarise` is used instead of the `data.table` method. So the bug in `dplyr:::summarise.data.table` remains.